# How to add form-data as JMETER body

Tags: json, jmeter, postman

I'm new to JMETER and trying to check the performance of my API but the API body is form-data and not sure how to add this in the JMETER body and test this API.

POSTMAN:

[image]

JMETER:

[image]

It would be great if someone help me to achieve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch to "Parameters" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and put your key/value pairs there:

[image]

---

Going forward be informed that you can easily convert your Postman scripts into JMeter by recording them.

1. Prepare JMeter for recording, the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

   - from JMeter's main menu choose File -> Templates -> Recording and click "Create"

     [image]
   - open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

     [image]
2. Prepare Postman for recording.

   - from Postman's main menu choose `File -> Settings` and click "Proxy"
   - Add a "custom proxy configuration" and use `127.0.0.1` as the proxy host and `8888` as the proxy port

     [image]
3. Execute your request/collection in Postman
4. JMeter will capture the requests and save them under [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

References:

- [Postman - Using a proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)
- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. Also I got this very useful one https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/fill-forms-and-submit-with-jmeter-made-easy

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to generate the request in jmeter via curl.
Tools >> Import via curl

From where you can get Curl for web App? | Developer tool of browser
Developer Tool >> Network tab and right click the API >> copy as curl